# SQL recurring start and end dates by key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

(SQL Server 2016) Given a key and date range described below:

```
Key    Date
a      1/1/2018
b      1/1/2018
a      1/2/2018
b      1/2/2018
a      1/3/2018
b      1/3/2018
a      1/4/2018
b      1/4/2018
a      1/5/2018
b      1/5/2018
a      1/13/2018
b      1/13/2018
a      1/14/2018
b      1/14/2018
a      1/15/2018
b      1/15/2018
a      1/16/2018
a      1/17/2018
etc.
```

Is it possible to return the following (the groups for each key are always a day apart):

```
Key    StartDate     EndDate
a      01/01/2018    01/05/2018   (first grouping for a)
a      01/13/2018    01/17/2018   (second grouping for a)
b      01/01/2018    01/05/2018
b      01/13/2018    01/15/2018
a      *new start*   *new end*
etc.
```

Edit:  Thank you for your comments.  In response to the questions below, I've tried Lead(), a cursor and multiple imbedded loops.  In most cases the result set is not correct (misplaced date or skipped key) or the time to execute is inflated.

Comment: what have you tried? what;s your dbms?

Comment: This looks like a Gaps and Islands problem. https://www.sqlshack.com/data-boundaries-finding-gaps-islands-and-more/

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, but it is a bit different from the standard problem, because your date sequences for the two keys are independent of each other.  You can do this with one `row_number()` difference form the date:

```
select key, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by date) as seqnum_k
      from t
     ) t
group by key, dateadd(day,  - seqnum_k, date)
order by key, min(date);
```

This is using ANSI standard syntax for date arithmetic; all databases support the functionality but the syntax might vary.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The result set you describe does return the bounding dates for each key e.g. 'a'   1/1/2018   1/1/2017, but how would one return the sub groups 'a' 1/1/2018  1/5/2018 and 'a' 1/13/2018 1/17/2018

Comment: @Semp . . . The second solution is more appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Quite new to Stackoverflow and I understand from reading some posts that 'Thank yous' aren't necessary, but your solution has saved me countless hours, if not days of frustration.  Thank you!